# How to serve files from gridfs using nginx (mongo 3.0)?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, gridfs

Is there any alternative to nginx-gridfs that can work with mongodb 3.0 with speed comparable to serving static files using only nginx?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [GridFS Fuse](https://github.com/mikejs/gridfs-fuse/) package. You can mount your GridFS files as a directory then just configure nginx to serve files from it as normal. I've never used it though and have no idea what the performance might be like.

Comment: It looks unmaintained for a long time and doesn't support authentication.

Comment: <shrug> You're not exactly drowning in choices... :)